# Adobe AIR copyto

Tags: air

I'm trying to move files from myLocation to the Desktop, but my copyTo syntax is wrong:

```
var myLocation = new air.File(myVolume); 
var files = myLocation.getDirectoryListing();
for (var f=0; f < files.length; f++){
    if (!files[f].isDirectory) {
        targetFile = air.File.desktopDirectory.resolvePath(files[f].name);
        files[f].copyTo(targetFile); // This line doesn't work.
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
files[f].moveTo(targetFile,true); // Overwrite
```